# Can the input report of a HID mouse be sent to another device via TCP/IP such that the mouse of that device can be controlled remotely?

Tags: tcp, embedded, usb, mouse, hid

I am able to read buffers representing the USB HID mouse input report that I am using in my local machine.

```
<Buffer 02 00 ee 07 00 00 00 03>
<Buffer 02 00 e6 09 00 00 00 03>
<Buffer 02 00 f3 07 00 00 00 03>
<Buffer 02 00 ec 09 00 00 00 03>
<Buffer 02 00 f8 05 00 00 00 03>
<Buffer 02 00 f2 08 00 00 00 03>
```

I have been able to set a TCP/IP server connection via which I am wanting to forward these HID mouse input report so that I can control the cursor on the remote computer. I have a port opened on the remote computer. How would I be able to send these buffers so that the cursor in the computer changes its location accordingly? How should the buffer readings be formatted?